# With JS add default date on TextBox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtDate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

how can with Jquery add default date. I do not know where and when to call this code:

```
function addDefaultDate() {
    if ($('#txtDate').val().length == 0) {
        var now = new Date();
        $('#txtDate').text(now.getDate() + '.' + now.getMonth() + '.' + now.getYear());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   var now = new Date();
   var myDate=(now.getMonth()+1) + '.' + now.getDate() + '.' + now.getFullYear();
   $("#txtDate").val(myDate);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate it as soon as page loads, you can use the `load` event eg:

```
window.onload = function(){
  addDefaultDate();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

since you're already using jquery i would suggest something like

`$(document).ready(function(){
    addDefaultDate();
});`

Comment: hmm yes and when to call it and how? i do not want to call body onload function.

Comment: well, when to call it is entirely up to you i think.  the code i posted above will run after the entire page has been loaded, similar to the window.onload function.  when would you like to to happen?  is there a button click or some other similar event?